# MPI_Bsend and MPI_Isend. How do they work?

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, mpi, nonblocking

using buffered send and non blocking send I was wondering how and if they implement a new level of parallelism in my application eventually generating a thread.
Imagine that a slave process generates a large amount of data and want to send it to the master. My idea was to start a buffered or non blocking send then immediately begin to compute the next result.

Just when I would have to send the new data I wold check if I can reuse the buffer. This would introduce a new level of parallelism in my application between CPU and communication. Does anybody knows how this is done in MPI ? Does MPI generate a new thread to handle the Bsend or Isend ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a nonblocking send using your own buffer (`MPI_Isend`).There is no need to worry about threading -- `ISend` should return immediately to let you continue your own code. You would then continue your work, and post an `MPI_Wait` request on the `MPI_Request` that you passed to `Isend`. This will then block until the buffer is free to use again. If you have space for several buffers, you could improve parallelism by allocating several buffers and using whichever becomes available through `MPI_Waitany`.

Comment: Another function worth mentioning is `MPI_Test`, which tells you if a transfer is completed without blocking.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer. In fact my question was about how this functions are implemented not about how to use them. What happens at system level with Isend ? A new thread is forked ?

Comment: @GBBL: Ah. The answer to your question is implementation specific (keep in mind that there are several popular MPI implementations). For mpich, with which I am most familiar, I think there is a continuously-running deamon process that handles client process requests node-locally through IPC.